# What filter should be used to filter TLS 1.3 client hello?

Tags: c++, ssl, networking, pcap, libpcap

Currently using `(tcp[tcp[12]/16*4]=22 and tcp[tcp[12]/16*4+5]=1)`, where `=22` represents handshake and `=1` represents client hello for both TLS 1.2/1.3 packets.

Since the above filter gives traffic to both TLS 1.2 and 1.3, I am not really finding a way/technique to differentiate TLS 1.3 or TLS 1.2 client hello traffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLS 1.3 support is announced in the `supported_versions` TLS extension. There is no clear offset for this extension in the ClientHello, i.e. one would need to properly parse the ClientHello structure. This is not doable with pcap filter rules.

Comment: I had a look at the Wireshark and compared client hello for both TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3, for both the cases I found supported_version TLS 1.3.

Comment: @PraveenPatel: `supported_versions` in ClientHello just shows what the client supports. What is then actually used as common protocol version can not be seen in ClientHello, since it is not known at this time what the server will agree on.  The information Wireshark shows about the used protocol version are derived from later messages in the TLS handshake.

Answer (score 0):

As Steffen mentioned, TLS 1.3 is negotiated in an extension inside the Client Hello, and confirmed by the server in the same extension in the Server Hello:

[image: TLS Server Hello with Supported Versions extension]

To filter for 0x0304 in this extension you would use this **Display Filter**:

`tls.handshake.extensions.supported_version == 0x0304`

This will catch any Client Hello or Server hello, with the TLS 1.3 hex code `0x0304`.

But be careful... just because a Client *proposes* TLS 1.3 does not mean the Server will accept... a server may very well elect to continue with a TLS 1.2 handshake.

In that case, the best way to definitively find each actual TLS 1.3 negotiated session is to combine the display filter above with another one which only matches on the Server Hello:

`(tls.handshake.extensions.supported_version == 0x0304) && (tls.handshake.type == 2)`

Granted, this will only show you the Server Hello's which confirm the TLS 1.3 session. It won't show you the entire TLS 1.3 session (like the other Records in the TLS Handshake, or the exchange of application data, and so on).